# Why does WP7 save GIFs as JPGs?

Tags: 7.x

When I save GIFs -- especially animated GIFs -- from a web page to my phone, it always saves it as a JPG.  This means that the animation is lost and only the first frame is preserved in JPG format.  Is there a way to get my WP7 to save GIFs as GIFs without messing around with the format (ie animated vs. non-animated)?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone (both 7 and 8) uses Silverlight to decode different image formats and until the Apollo update for Windows Phone 8, WP did not support `.gif` file types unless developers used a third party library such as [.NET Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) to decode animated `gif` types.

So to answer your question, saving an animated `.gif` from Internet Explorer on to your phone will (at this point anyway) result in you losing all frames except the first.

[You're not the only one who faces this issue though: there is a feature request that has been made on the Windows Phone User Voice site to allow for this capability. Check it out](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2663177-allow-saving-of-animated-gifs-from-internet-explor).